# Not able to scrape a webpage using scrapy or Beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, python-requests

I had tried to **scrape** the search result in below website
https://www.guelphchamber.com/find/#/action/AdvancedSearch/cid/119/id/201/listingType/O?value=&city=14

But the response text is showing the body with the javascript arrays.Did i need to use selenium instead of the requests

```
import requests


session = requests.session()
url="https://www.guelphchamber.com/find#/action/AdvancedSearch/cid/119/id/201/listingType/O?value=&city=14"
response=requests.get(url)
```

Comment: If you mean that you need to type into the search box and then scrape the results, then yes, selenium would work way better than using requests.

Comment: No need of search Just scrap the results in that page

Comment: Gotcha... The site is running javascript so you'll need to use selenium.

Comment: disable your javascrip on browser and reload page, if it has what you want then you can scrape it by `requests`

Comment: Is it possible to disbale in requests

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap